# Issues signing MSI file using YubiKey Manager with .crt certificate (not with a .PFX)

Tags: ssl-certificate, windows-installer, code-signing, yubico, yubikey

I have been trying to sign my MSI file using YubiKey Manager with a `.crt` cert (not a PFX due to recent [CAB and Sectigo's rules](https://support.sectigo.com/IS_KnowledgeDetailPage?Id=kA03l000000BoIs)) but couldn't find a good way to make it work.

I have followed these recommended articles([1](https://signmycode.com/resources/how-to-use-yubikey-for-code-signing-purpose), [2](https://support.yubico.com/hc/en-us/articles/360016614840-Code-Signing-with-the-YubiKey-on-Windows)) but ended up getting this generic error when trying to sign with `SignTool` as recommended.

> SignTool Error: No certificates were found that met all the given criteria.

I am using this following `SignTool` command to sign my MSI.

```
.\signtool.exe sign -s "My" -sha1 "<thumbprint>" /td sha256 /fd sha256 -tr http://timestamp.sectigo.com .\myfile.msi
```

I am pretty sure that the certificate is present in the `Personal` cert store but in `.crt` format. My hunch is that the `SignTool` is expecting a `.PFX` which unfortunately cannot be provided in this context as the Private Key will be in the YubiKey Token and Sectigo won't allow us to convert the .crt to .pfx.

I've come across numerous solutions addressing the generic `SignTool` error, but unfortunately, none of them have proven effective in resolving my specific issue.

I appreciate any assistance or insights into resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download Yubikey Drivers such as "Yubico PIV Tool", "YubiKey Manager" and "YubiKey Smart Card Minidriver" from https://www.yubico.com/support/download/smart-card-drivers-tools. After that they need to begin the signing process from the start.

Comment: Hi [JP Mehta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21526649/jp-mehta) I have the YubiKey Smart Card Mini Driver installed and have been trying by connecting the YubiKey via YubiKey Manager. I can also check my code signing cert with `certutil -scinfo` command however, `Signtool` says `SignTool Error: No certificates were found that met all the given criteria.` which I think `Signtool` is expecting a .PFX but YubiKey contains a .CRT was this an issue?

Comment: Hi  @venkata-n-bhupathi
did you manage to find a solution to the “no certificate found” problem?

Comment: No, not yet. The previous certificate seems to be a dead end for some reason, so I had to request a new one. However, now I'm encountering a different issue. The error message I'm seeing is: `SignTool Error: An unexpected internal error has occurred. Error information: "Could not associate private key with certificate." (-2147024 891/0x80070005)`. I will update you if I manage to resolve this new problem